# "Cannot find installed version of python-django or python3-django" when running celery worker

Tags: python, django, celery

When I run the command via ubuntu 15.04 terminal

> celery worker -A celery_blog -l inf -c 5

I always get

> Cannot find installed version of python-django or python3-django.

Though I have installed django for python 2.x as well as 3.x, you may refer the attached screenshot also.

[image]

Also, why even it's asking for django when running celery worker?

Comment: How did you install Django? If it is in a virtual environment, then you must activate the virtual environment before starting the celery worker.

Comment: I have installed globally.

Comment: can you run 'which python-django' or 'which python3-django'?

Comment: @lapinkoira what you mean by that?

Comment: If you type on your shell 'which python-django' it tells you where is the application bin located on

Comment: In case that command gives you an error then there you have the problem/solution

Answer (score 7):

Solution 1:

```
 pip install Django
```

Solution 2: 
ubuntu version > 14.04. `python3-django` is a package available in the repos for Ubuntu 15.04. It isn't in the default repos for Ubuntu 14.04

```
apt-get install python3-django
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of different ways in which you can install Django depending upon your needs and how you want to configure your development environment.

Global Install from Packages:

> sudo apt-get update

> sudo apt-get install python-django

You can test that the installation was successful by typing:

> django-admin --version

Global Install through pip:

> sudo apt-get update

Now you can install pip. If you plan on using Python version 2, install using the following commands:

> sudo apt-get install python-pip

If, instead, you plan on using Python 3, use this command:

> sudo apt-get install python3-pip

Now that you have pip, we can easily install Django. If you are using Python 2, you can type:

> sudo pip install django

If you are using Python 3, use the pip3 command instead:

> sudo pip3 install django

You can verify that the installation was successful by typing:

> django-admin --version

Global Install through pip.